# Question about nested input requirements

Tags: microeconomics

In Michael Carter's "Foundation of Mathematical Economics" we have the following exercise:

Prove that the input requirement sets are nested. That is, prove that $V(y') \supseteq V(y)$ $ \forall $ $y' \leq y$

This seems a bit odd. I have the following:

Let $X \in V(y)$ Then $(y,-x) \in Y$ where Y is the production possibility set. 
Then by free disposal, it follows that $(y',-x) \in Y $ $\forall$  $y' \leq y$

It seems like the conclusion should be then that $V(y) \supseteq V(y') \forall y' \leq y$

In words: It seems like the input requirement for out y' where $y' \leq y$ should be less than or equal to the input requirement for y. And because of this, the input requirement for y should contain the input requirements for y'.

Can someone give some direction here? Why is it that we are saying the input requirements for a lesser output is somehow a super set for the input requirements of a greater output?